# how to remove unnecessary double quote from dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

i have following dictionary and I need to remove the unnecessary double quote around the keys and values in the dictionary object:

```
d={" 'John'": "'car': 2, 'laptop': 4, 'comp': 3"," 'Jim'": "'car':2, 'laptop':3 ,'computer':2"}
```

I want the dictionary object to be like:

```
d={'John': 'car': 2, 'laptop': 4, 'comp': 3,'Jim':'car':2, 'laptop':3 ,'computer':2}
```

here's the code that I tried but gives error:

```
ast.literal_eval(d.replace('""', '"'))
```

initially i had a string object which i tried to parse to dict and I got the above initial d={} so when I try to do

```
print(d['john'])   gives error
```

but when I do d["'john'"] it prints the correct value. so I was trying to fixt it

Comment: dictionary does not have replace method, only str has. And also stuff in d are not sharing the same pattern. I'd suggest to loop through every key/value pair, and process them by their patterns.

Comment: Also `"a"` and `'a'` are really the same thing. Not sure why you want to do that.

Comment: Not sure if this will fully help you, but its a start: `new_d = {}`

`for i in d:
    j = [b for b in i if b != ' ']
    j = ''.join([h for h in j if h != "'"])
    new_d[j] = d[i]`

Comment: They're not really unnecessary as they have different meanings. I'd parse them correctly, *then* store them in the dict, rather then fixup the dict later.

Comment: The double quote is not unnecessary and the dict you want is invalid syntax in python. It should be `d={'John': {'car': 2, 'laptop': 4, 'comp': 3},'Jim':{'car':2, 'laptop':3 ,'computer':2}}`

Comment: well I tried to parse a string object to dict and I got the above initial d={} so when I try to print d['john'] I get error. but when I do d["'john'"] it prints the correct value. so I was trying to fixt it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to convert it into a dict's dict?
You may try this code:

```
d={" 'John'": "'car': 2, 'laptop': 4, 'comp': 3"," 'Jim'": "'car':2, 'laptop':3 ,'computer':2"}
new_d = {}
for x in d: #x will be 'John' and 'Jim', notice the single quotes will be remained because it's part of the string while double quotes removed as the mark of string
    code = 'new_d['+x+']={'+d[x]+'}' # new_d['John']={'car': 2, 'laptop': 4, 'comp': 3}
    exec code # This means execute string code as python expression
print new_d
```

Comment: This is kind of neat but given that the question is from someone who does not have a strong grasp of Python it might be helpful to explain what is going on - especially the +x+ and the exec code lines

Comment: @locoyou thanks for reply. your solution did worked but may be I didn't parsed the string correctly or for some reason I can't get the value for d['John'] whereas d["'John'"] would give the correct values. what's the right way to fix that?

Comment: @user3399326 I think you were confused because the quote. In python, single and double quote can both mark a string. 'John' and "John" is the same and the string object is John without any quote, while " 'John' " is 'John' and ' "John" ' is "John". In your original dictionary, the key is 'John' not John

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the source is trusted:

```
d2 = {eval(k):v for k, v in d.iteritems()}
```